# How to display price on category view using Magento?

Tags: php, magento, xhtml

I am looking for some suggestions from experts.

I would like to find out how to display price-box on category grid view. For better explanation I attaching src below.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I cant upload images to my post yet(Im just signed up recently). However I can provide the url link instead of src. My current site is : http://www.thebodyshop.ie/bath-body/new-in.html ; and I would like to change the category view like this : http://www.thebodyshop.co.uk/bath-body-care/new-in.aspx#/new-in.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look @

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Site code

```
<div class="batch">
   <h4 class="name"><a href="/bath-body/new-in/honeymaniatm-body-butter.html" title="HONEYMANIA™ BODY BUTTER">HONEYMANIA™ BODY BUTTER</a></h4>
   <a class="button shop" href="/bath-body/new-in/honeymaniatm-body-butter.html" title="DISCOVER">DISCOVER<span></span></a>
   <div style="display:none"> <<<<<<---- Here is the issue
   <div class="price-box"> 
   <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-1049">
   <span class="price">€7.95</span>                                    </span>
```

You need to edit

> /app/design/frontend/base/{yourtheme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Remove

> `<div style="display:none">`

(do a search for `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` it should be around this line)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I checked and it is the same as yours. Also I looked the styles.css and there is no rule as: display:none! I have no clue why is not displaying the price-box.

Comment: Take a look at my update `<div style="display:none">`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I removed the "display:none" tag and the prices visible now. Im still working on the styling as something effecting the responsiveness. However your support was super fast!! Thanks again!!

Comment: Can you please suggest a solution for styling the price in the style.css? This is my code but does not work(                 .regular-price .price {
  color: #e2007a;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'gill-ss-std-bold' Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}  )

Comment: Did you try adding the code above to line #756 in style.css?

Comment: I did try to modify the line #756 but it dose not working. However when I editing in the page source its working but only in the internet browser.

Comment: The line #756 empty on the styles.css sheet

Comment: Search for this line `/* Regular price */
.regular-price {}
.regular-price .price`

Comment: I found it on the styles.css still not working with my style /********** < Product Prices */
.price { white-space:nowrap !important; }

.price-box {}
.price-box .price { font-weight:bold;}

/* Regular price */
.regular-price {}
.regular-price .price { font-weight:bold;}

Comment: Sorry! It was my mistake, I missed one folder :/  Thanks for your guidance!!